# I have a custom chopper motorcycle wiring issue

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, relay

I have a custom chopper motorcycle. I have made a sequencing tail light system in the rear.
The sequencing works fine until the brakes are applied.  The brake lights causes the sequencing to pulse.
I have a DRUGZ unit/relay that has a default to the brake side.  However when the turn (momentary switch)
is pressed the relay cuts off the brake and allows the turn to function.  The problem is the timer/sequencers have a dead spot or triggers the relay to open/close. (clicking sound)  MY thought was to have a latching relay so when the turn signal is applied it maintains the closed position for the turn signal. I can't have any type of relay or component that needs power from the battery as this will drain  the battery and chopper won't start. Any advice would be appreciated.  No motorcycle retailer has a resolution to this issue

Comment: No datasheet link to product, no wiring schematic, no help, I suspect.

Comment: So, power that extra relay via the ignition or even from the alternator so it only gets power once the alternator is producing power.

Comment: It sounds like the power is feeding back through to the brakes (taking the back route). A diode in line might solve your issue.